# What is a multi-valued dependency?

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am trying to understand how to put a relation in to 4nf. However, I am having a hard time understand what a multi-valued dependency is. My textbook defines it as:

> Represents a dependency between attributes (for example, A,B,C) in a relation such that for each value A there is a set of values for B and a set of values for C. However, the set of values for B and C are independent of each other.

Database Systems by Thomas Connolly and Carolyn Begg.

Is it stating a Multi-valued dependency is a set of functional dependencies that meet the following requirements?

A->B ^ A->C ^ ~(B->C)

The textbok goes on to suggest these constraints usually exist in 1:n relationships which make me think that there might be a implicit condition that I am missing.

Comment: It's "multi-valued" or "multivalued" dependency or MVD. This is a FAQ, please google your title (with & without site:stackoveflow.com). A MVD is not a FD or set of FDs or condition involving FDs. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37199044/3404097) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28782476/3404097).

Comment: If FD X ->Y holds in a table with attribute set R (X and Y are attribute sets) then MVD X ->> Y also holds. And whenever X ->> Y holds so does MVD X ->> (R - Y). Maybe this has something to do with your "requirements" hypothesis?

Comment: An excellent answer + example can be found [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133757/111810).

Comment: That textbook is extremely poor & that quote is unclear & useless. (However, if you think it might be saying what you say, why do you think it's saying that?)